# Is this question about long-running codes on remote servers on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked the following question:

[How to launch a long-running Python code in a Docker container running on a remote server](https://askubuntu.com/q/1375529/831094)

but I was wondering whether it would be more in-topic on Stack Overflow or Software Recommendations. What do you think? If I remember correctly, cross-posting is frowned upon in the Stack Exchange hierarchy, so if I post on another site I should first delete my question here. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, you say:

> The Docker container is based on an Ubuntu image

In [this recent answer about whether something is on topic or not](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19807/1222991), Zanna (a moderator), said:

> TL;DR: not everything about {subject} is on topic here, but using software relating to {subject} on Ubuntu is on topic.

<sup>**Note:** The {subject} was originally about Bitcoin, but is just as valid when asking questions related to Python, Docker, and anything else that can run *on* Ubuntu.</sup>

So, given that:

1. the Docker container is built from an Ubuntu 18.04 image
2. you are asking for solutions related to that container (as opposed to the host OS, which is not stated)

I would say that it is on topic for AskUbuntu

Comment: Perfect! As a matter of fact, the question was even a duplicate, as user @muru kindly pointed out.