# Question correctly flagged as duplicate, should I delete it?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I asked a question yesterday

[How to launch a long-running Python code in a Docker container running on a remote server](https://askubuntu.com/q/1375529/831094)

and then it crossed my mind that maybe the question was off-topic

[Is this question about long-running codes on remote servers in-topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19814/831094)

As it turns out, the question was in-topic and actually a duplicate. Also, the question of which my question is a duplicate has some excellent answers. I haven't been very active on Stack Exchange in the last years, but I seem to remember that duplicates are bad. Should I delete my question, or do I just leave it there?

Comment: Maybe not the best reason, but you will get the Internet points for the upvotes that come along from leaving it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good quality duplicates are good. You can leave your question there. Other people might land on your post and find the excellent answers posted to the other one through the link.